# Corresponding dependency and target lists in Makefile

Tags: makefile

In a makefile, suppose I have two corresponding dependency and target lists, like this:

```
SRC = x.c y.c z.c
OBJS = x.o y.o z.o
```

Of course, my example is more complicated than this, but I want to know if it is possible to automatically create targets x.o, y.o, z.o depending on x.c, y.c, z.c respectively, like this:

```
x.o: x.c
y.o: y.c
z.o: z.c
```

Comment: I already have OBJS created from SRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question was how to create rules for each of these targets, not how to create `OBJS` from `SRC` (although it's good to do that!).

The simplest way is to use the already-built-in rule in make that knows how to do it; you don't need to write your own.  Just use:

```
all: $(OBJS)
```

and they'll all be created.  You can control the compiler by setting the `CC` variable, the preprocessor flags by setting the `CPPFLAGS` variable, and the other compiler flags by setting the `CFLAGS` variable.

If you DO really want to write your own rule, then pattern rules will do that for you easily:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: The problem is that the source files are all in different directories. So I assume the best way to do this is to create multiple pattern rules for each of the source directories?

Comment: If there's more to the situation you should put that into the question.  Do you want the objects to appear in the same directory as the sources?  If so, then the above will work as-is.  If you want the objects to be created in different directories then yes, you'll have to create a different rule for each different directory.

Comment: The objects are supposed to be in their own directory, and the sources are in different directories, so I have decided to make different pattern rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substitution references](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs):

```
OBJS = $(SRC:.c=.o)
```

or [patsubst](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
```